# jQuery show/hide toggler for faq list elements

Tags: jquery, html, list

I've been trying to get an faq styled list created where there is a toggle button that when clicked slides open the respective answer to the question. However, I can't seem to get it to work at all and was wondering if I could have some help?

The main issue I'm having is when one button is clicked, they're all expanding and showing the answers. I was wondering if I could implement something so it targets the child element and toggles that?

Here is my code...

**jQuery**

```
   $j("ul.nav .view_faq_answer").hide();
   $j("a.toggler").click(function() { 
       $j(this).next('.view_faq_answer').slideToggle(); 
   });
```

**HTML**

```
   <ul class="faq">
      <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggler">+</a>
          <div class="view_faq">
             <div class="view_faq_question">question</div>
             <div class="view_faq_answer">answer</div>
          </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

I've stripped out the PHP so it's easier to see and obviously there's no need for any CSS as it's all styled up as it needs to be. I just don't know how to get this to work for each individual element.

I have tried (this).next and (this).parent but had no luck. Any help please?

Comment: This should work. Is this the real html ?

Comment: please, prepare a working jsFiddle to see the problem

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgbejvfq/) Works just fine for me

Comment: @Harben of course... You only have a single `li`

Answer (score 3):

It's because `.view_faq_answer` is not a sibling of `.toggler` - it's a child of `.view_faq`, which is a sibling. Robin Leboeuf's answer should work, but as an alternative:

```
$j(this).next('.view_faq').children('.view_faq_answer').slideToggle();
```

Edit: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n65swq19/)

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more semantic HTML for this would be to use a `<dl>` - with `<dt>` as the question, and `<dd>` as the answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/gyx5kfp3/

Comment: I prefer this answer as it provides 2 elements and not three as the others do. The question should be the toggle as used here..

Answer (score 1):

Try using .parent().find() instead of .next()

```
   $("ul.nav .view_faq_answer").hide();
   $("a.toggler").click(function() { 
       $(this).parent().find('.view_faq_answer').slideToggle(); 
   } );
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m7tr8afe/)